# Amazon spot instance deployment antipattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bigdata, analytics, devops

I'm pretty sure I'm doing things the wrong way and I'd like to know the right way.

The problem I face is:

- I have a distributed batch job
- I use AWS spot instances to fulfill it
- always a one-off request (so I'm after simple solutions)
- The instances need some configuration and setup, and they need to be sent tasks to do

I typically solve it like this:

- Bring up one worker and configure it
- Save an image of it
- Then bring up all the other instances
- Then I'll do a big, annoying, copy paste job, to basically create a shell script like this:

  `$HOST=123.123.123.1 $TASK=task1 ssh ubuntu@$HOST task_runner $TASK &
  $HOST=123.123.123.2 $TASK=task2 ssh ubuntu@$HOST task_runner $TASK &
  $HOST=123.123.123.3 $TASK=task3 ssh ubuntu@$HOST task_runner $TASK &
  ...`

I'd like to do this better, so I'm after ways to make it easier to:

1. Set up AWS instances. Sometimes there's a boot-time code that needs to be run, and this means more big tasks like the one above
2. Get the instance list. No more copy-pasting!
3. Run all the tasks on all the instances.
4. Shut them down when I'm done

Ideally I'd like to cover the whole lifecycle, end to end.

Lastly, I want something pretty simple. Because it's a one off task, I don't really want to have to deal with a whole lot of config options and wiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) to do this reasonably simply.

Your Ansible playbook would look something like:

```
- name: Stage instance(s)
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
      keypair: mykeypair
      instance_type: m1.small
      security_group: sg-123456abc
      image: ami-123456abc
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-123456abc
      count: 5

  tasks:
    - name: Create spot instance
      ec2:
        spot_price: 0.24
        spot_wait_timeout: 600
        keypair: {{ keypair }}
        group_id: {{ security_group }}
        instance_type: {{ instance_type }}
        image: {{ image }}
        vpc_subnet_id: {{ vpc_subnet_id }}
        assign_public_ip: no
        count: {{ count }}
        wait: yes
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instances to host group
      add_host: hostname={{item.private_ip}} groupname=task_minions
      with_items: ec2.instances

    - name: Wait for the instances to boot by checking the ssh port
      wait_for: host={{item.private_dns_name}} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
      with_items: ec2.instances

- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: task_minions
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
    - name: Some configuration
      yum:
        ...

- name: Run tasks
  hosts: task_minions
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
    - name: Run all tasks on all task_minions
      command:
        task_runner {{ item }}
      with_items:
        - task_1
        - task_2
        ...

- name: Terminate instance(s)
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Terminate instances that were previously launched
      ec2:
        state: 'absent'
        instance_ids: '{{ ec2.instance_ids }}'
```

I have less experience with other configuration management tools but I'm sure they could also be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

couple of things to try / think about:

1) you should look into building an AMI with everything you need from the image + the hook that runs the boot time code. This should allow you to just boot up images with this AMI and not having to worry about building it

2) use an SQS queue to dispatch the tasks. this way the workers can just pull from that queue and you can tell pretty easily when they're done. (queue goes to 0 with no messages in flight).

3) For extra awesomeness. Combine the SQS dispatching with autoscalling: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-using-sqs-queue.html This way you can have autoscalling spin up/spin down your instances whenever there is work. The only thing you need to do is to push things to the queue.

4) For mega extra awesomeness. Do all 3 above + put everything in a CloudFormation template and spin up a Cloudformation Stack. If you ever need to tinker with the setup (change images, queues, config, etc) you can simply tweak the template and redeploy.

Hope this helps.